# Cannot workout issue with python code

Tags: python, ubuntu, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, ibeacon

I've been working on a program to access an iBeacon data over bluetooth on my Pi 3 running ubuntu mate 16.04 with out the use of `sudo` so it can be called from another script. My code works fine when I initialise the class in the `if__name__=="__main__":` section?? (not sure of the exact name)

**Problem**
when I created the `ibeacon class` to allow the program to be called from another script using a single line I cannot seem to access the device even though the two setups are identical as far as I can see.

Here is the full code, if you want to run it you will need `pctrl` and `bluepy` to install them use `sudo apt-get install python-prctl` and `sudo pip install bluepy` and lastly change the permission of bluesy-helper executable using `sudo chmod 4755 bluepy-helper` to remove the need for sudo to access the bluetooth module. I also added `pi ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/pi/python/ibeacon.py` to the last line of `visudo` but not sure if that is necessary.

when `mode = 0` it will not work but, using `mode = 1` will, I cannot nut it out, please help!

```
import time, math, datetime, prctl
import numpy as np
from os import getcwd
from threading import Thread
from bluepy.btle import Scanner, DefaultDelegate


class KalmanFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, process_variance,estimated_measurement_variance):
        self.process_variance = process_variance
        self.estimated_measurement_variance = estimated_measurement_variance
        self.posteri_estimate = 1.0
        self.posteri_error_estimate = 2.0

    def input_latest_noisy_measurement(self, measurement):
        priori_estimate = self.posteri_estimate
        priori_error_estimate = self.posteri_error_estimate + self.process_variance

        blending_factor = priori_error_estimate / (priori_error_estimate + self.estimated_measurement_variance)
        self.posteri_estimate = priori_estimate + blending_factor * (measurement - priori_estimate)
        self.posteri_error_estimate = (1 - blending_factor) * priori_error_estimate

    def get_latest_estimated_measurement(self):
        return self.posteri_estimate


class ScanDelegate(DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        self.RSSI = self.DEV = self.dist = self.dist_kal = 0
        self.stoppped = False

        self.process_variance = 1e-3
        self.estimated_measurement_variance = 0.25 ** 2 
        self.kalman_filter = KalmanFilter(self.process_variance, self.estimated_measurement_variance)
        DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)
        self.scanner = Scanner()

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True

    def start(self):
        # start the thread to read frames from the device output
        Thread(target=self.update, name="iBeacon").start()
        print("Staring ibeacon")
        return self

    def distance(self, n=2.0, txpower=53):
        return (abs(self.RSSI)/(10.0*n*math.log10(math.exp(1)))) - (txpower/(10.0*n*math.log10(math.exp(1)))) # convert RSSI to Distance

    def update_file(self):
        f = open('ibeacon.txt', 'w')
        ts = time.time()
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        string = '%s\t%2.2f' % (st, self.dist_kal)
        f.write(string)
        f.close()

    def update(self):
        prctl.set_name("iBeacon")
        count = 0
        while(not self.stoppped):
            try:
                devices = self.scanner.scan(0.20)
                for dev in devices:
                    # print(dev.addr)
                    if dev.addr == '00:15:83:00:81:f0':
                        self.RSSI = dev.rssi
                        self.DEV = dev.addr
                        self.dist = self.distance()
                        self.kalman_filter.input_latest_noisy_measurement(self.dist)
                        self.dist_kal = self.kalman_filter.get_latest_estimated_measurement()
                        self.update_file()
                        count = 0
                        #print "Device %s, RSSI=%d dB" % (dev.addr,dev.rssi)
            except:
                self.dist_kal = 0
                if count >= 4:
                    print "no ibeacon found"
                    self.update_file()
                count += 1
                time.sleep(1)

class iBeacon():
    def __init__(self):
        self.scan = ScanDelegate()
        self.scanner = self.scan.scanner.withDelegate(self.scan)
        self.scan.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":


    beacon = iBeacon()

    while(1):
        print "address:", beacon.scan.DEV, "RSSI:", beacon.scan.RSSI, "distance:", beacon.scan.dist, "kalman distance:", beacon.scan.dist_kal
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

**Terminal output - mode=0**

```
pi@pi:~/python$ python ibeacon.py
Staring ibeacon
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
no ibeacon found
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 10
^\^\^\^\|Quit (core dumped)
```

**Terminal output - mode=1**

```
pi@pi:~/python$ python ibeacon.py
Staring ibeacon
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 0
address: 0 RSSI: 0 distance: 0 kalman distance: 0
address: 00:15:83:00:81:f0 RSSI: -65 distance: 1.3815510558 kalman distance: 1.36999450577
address: 00:15:83:00:81:f0 RSSI: -65 distance: 1.3815510558 kalman distance: 1.36999450577
address: 00:15:83:00:81:f0 RSSI: -65 distance: 1.3815510558 kalman distance: 1.36999450577
address: 00:15:83:00:81:f0 RSSI: -65 distance: 1.3815510558 kalman distance: 1.36999450577
address: 00:15:83:00:81:f0 RSSI: -63 distance: 1.1512925465 kalman distance: 1.26143036974
address: 00:15:83:00:81:f0 RSSI: -64 distance: 1.26642180115 kalman distance: 1.26312146783
^\Quit (core dumped)
```

Comment: You haven't really said what the problem is. What is failing and where? Do you get an error? What do you see? Also, Python is not Java; there's not really a need for things like "wrapper classes".

Comment: Is that clearer now? It cannot seem to access the bluetooth output when using the ibeacon class to initialise the program.

Comment: But what output do you get when mode == 0? What happens?

Comment: I can't see a screenshot that is on your desktop... In any case, there's no reason to post a picture, copy and paste the output as text into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ScanDelegate.update` method is trying to access a global variable called `scanner`. This doesn't exist when mode is 0.

The reason you don't see this is because you wrap that method in a blank except, which catches *all* errors including the NameError that would be raised here. That's why you must never, ever do that; you should only catch the specific exceptions you are expecting to be able to deal with.

Comment: Yes that is the error I am getting once I added your suggestion - I will add the exceptions I expect from now on. Do you have any suggestions on how I can better set up my code to allow me to call this program from one line as mode=0 shows?

Comment: You need some way of passing the scanner object into the update method. However I don't know how the Scanner and ScanDelegate classes work, so I can't help much further.

Comment: Problem solved!

You gave the right error for me to track down, solution has been added to code to allow anyone else to use this code for the own use.